# Caching pip dependencies in docker builder with github actions

Tags: pip, dockerfile, github-actions

I'm using github actions to build a docker image. I cache the docker layers (which works well) but sometimes layers aren't reused (not sure why! i'm following [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) but ignore that aside) and I'm using a fallback pip cache to speed up the build.

Dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM python:3.10-slim
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&  pip cache dir
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip/ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I'm using the `--mount` flag [from syntax 1.2](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#build-mounts-run---mount) which "allows the build container to cache directories for compilers and package managers"

Github actions cache (which i'd like to mount on the build container):

```
- name: Cache pip
  uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: /root/.cache/pip
    key: pip-{{ hashFiles('requirements*.txt') }}
```

and docker build

```
- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    cache-from: type=gha
    cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
```

How do I mount the pip cache into the docker builder container?

Right now the cache is empty using this command in the dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip/ pip cache info && ls /root/.cache/pip
```

outputs:

```
19 RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip/ pip cache info && ls /root/.cache/pip
#19 0.387 Package index page cache location: /root/.cache/pip/http
#19 0.387 Package index page cache size: 0 bytes
#19 0.387 Number of HTTP files: 0
#19 0.387 Wheels location: /root/.cache/pip/wheels
#19 0.387 Wheels size: 0 bytes
#19 0.387 Number of wheels: 0
#19 DONE 0.4s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this works actually and dropped my install time from 180s to 30-40s it's a little funky but I got it working for both pip and yarn (yarn doesn't save anytime tho since I'm using yarn 1 and most of the time is spent on I/O reading writing)

You'll need buildx v0.8.0+ to support [`--build-context`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#build-context) and you'll need docker frontend syntax v1.4+ to support [`RUN --mount`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#build-mounts-run---mount) I also use [github actions cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) to handle installing and caching pip dependencies. It looks like this

1. github cache action, install pip requirements, also get pip cache dir: `::set-output name=pip-dir::$(pip cache dir)` to use in next step
2. I'm using [docker build and push action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action), which supports `--build-context`:
   `build-contexts: pip_cache=${{steps.vars.outputs.pip-dir}}`
3. Update the docker file to use the pip_cache build context
   `RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip,from=pip_cache pip install -r requirements.txt`

On build pip install using cached packages:

```
#22 RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip,from=pip_cache pip install -r requirements.txt
#22 0.587 Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.34.2)
#22 0.592 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
#22 1.440 Collecting aenum==2.2.3
#22 1.442   Using cached aenum-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
#22 1.495 Collecting alembic==1.7.3
#22 1.498   Using cached alembic-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (208 kB)
```

It's mostly worth it for the time saved building wheels, but downloads are pretty snappy regardless.

Comment: Won't you need to keep the docker container in sync with the OS of the github runner here? It would be really great if could keep the requirements install inside the container to avoid any problems with different OS.